# Johnson's vs Floyd-Warshall for dense graphs

Tags: shortest-path

I often read that [Floyd-Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) is a good fit for **dense** graphs and [Johnson's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm) for **sparse** ones.  While it's easy to see why Johnson outperforms Floyd-Warshall on sparse graphs, I'm noticing that Johnson's with **Fibonacci Heaps** does **no worse** than Floyd-Warshall in terms of asymptotic runtime.

More specifically, from what I see, for dense graphs we have:

- Floyd-Warshall runs in $O(V^3)$
- Johnson's algorithm with a Fibonacci Heap runs in $O(VE + V^2\text{lg}V$) which for a dense graph would also be $O(V^3)$

If so, what are the exact benefits of **Floyd-Warshall** over **Johnson**'s? Is it runtime differences in practice? Space complexity? Something else?

To put it more bluntly (at the risk of oversimplifying this matter) could one say e.g. *"Always use Johnson's over Floyd-Warshall"*?.

Comment: The five lines of code for Floyd-Warshall fit on the back of a beer coaster. On the other hand I need two hours and a blackboard to start explaining Fibonacci heaps.